# SQL Function INPUT Table Type in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, sql-server-2016

For MS SQL 2016

I have user table 'table TYPE t_Table(Id int, String nvarchar (max))'

Also I have function 'f_get(@T t_Table)'

There is some code... equivalent' STRING_AGG' --*I Can not use this function because of the version of SQL*

The function works correct when I use type t_Table...

```
 DECLARE @T t_Table
 INSERT INTO @T
 SELECT 1, 'John' UNION
 SELECT 2, 'Mark'

 SELECT f_get(@T)...
```

But I would like to use this function in QUERY

```
 SELECT f_get(
 SELECT 1, 'John' UNION
 SELECT 2, 'Mark'
)
```

.... but it doesnot work

Or in query

```
 SELECT * FROM orders o
 OUTER APLLY f_get(
 SELECT ID, Name as String FROM table t WHERE t.OrderId = o.OrderId 
  )
```

Is there any way how can I do this?
Thank you
David

Comment: Skipping the declaration part of a table type/ constructing the table inline is impossible AFAIK.

Comment: You can't pass a SQL statement to a Function, like you are trying to do, no. That's not how they work. Providing a Table Type Parameter, in this case, is the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible to do what you are trying to do.   To pass a table to a Table-Valued parameter in a function, you have to pass it a variable of the expected table type.   You can't pass it with an inline SELECT statement.